# Dot syntax vs square brackets when setting background color in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm still learning IOS SDK so hopefully this makes sense.  I am still trying to wrap my head around using dot syntax.  Could some one explain why this code doesn't work but the second one does?

Not working:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionView *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Working:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionView *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

I just don't understand why the first code won't work as well.  I am using the newest version of Xcode.  Was the setBackgroundColor method deprecated into something else?

Comment: The two are equivalent (apart from the slight syntactical difference that dot notation is checked by the compiler for declarations). If #1 works, #2 should work identically.

Comment: Wait you are casting the cell from `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` into a UICollectionView which is the wrong type. Otherwise these should be equivalent as @H2CO3 said

Comment: The compiler should be warning in both cases. I doubt that the code we're being shown is the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use dot notation, always keep in mind that you **don't** need to change the property name in any way. So if you say have:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *message;
```

The compiler takes care of the `setter` and `getter` methods for you, so all you have to do to use the dot notation on this property is this:

```
self.message;         // getter
self.message = @"hi"; // setter
// the only difference being - which side of the = sign is your property at
```

If on the other hand you want to change the behaviour of the setter/getter, you *then* have to you define the `setMessage` method in the following way, to implement (not override) your own `setter`:

```
- (void)setMessage:(NSString *)message {
    // custom code...
    _message = message;
}
```

Maybe that's what you're confusing. As for `setBackgroundColor`, it's still there, you just don't access it using the *dot notation*, which, by the way, allows for all kinds of neat stuff like this:

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic) int someNumber;

// .m
self.someNumber = 5;   // calls the setter, sets property to 5
self.someNumber += 10; // calls the setter and getter, sets property to 15
self.someNumber++;     // calls the setter and getter, sets property to 16
```