# UIProgressView scaling inconsistency issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Total newb here.

What is the difference between this

```
_myUIProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_myUIProgressView.transform, 1.0, 0.3);
```

and this:

```
[_myUIProgressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.3)];
```

besides the brevity. Why would you favor one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot Notation vs Method Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386256/dot-notation-vs-method-notation) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575545/dot-syntax-vs-square-brackets-when-setting-background-color-in-collection-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 2 calls are functionally identical. The only difference is syntax.

The first is called dot notation. The second is a method call to the setter.

Dot notation is an alternative way to invoke a property's setter or getter, and it does exactly the same thing as the other syntax.

Some people (mostly old school C programmers) don't like the dot syntax. I'm an old C programmer, but I like it.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that in this specific case the *method* calls are identical, but the two CoreGraphics functions being used to generate the scale are actually different (`CGAffineTransformScale` vs `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`). I assume that @misterkeeter was asking about the dot syntax though.

Comment: Not actually so, in first example, view's transform is transformed, however in second example scale transform is explicitly set to view. Say if you call first code multiple times, your view will get thiner with each call. If you will call second code, you view will get thiner, but second and further calls won't change it

Comment: @petrokorienev's explanation gets to the heart of the issue I was having. At the same time the clarification of syntax was helpful as well.

Comment: Good catch lxt. I didn't read the code carefully enough. And good point Petro.